# Efficiency in JOIN: join on column or value?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance, join

Suppose I have table A with a numeric column `MONTH` always constant and another column of unique IDs

| MONTH | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 202209 | 1 |
| 202209 | 2 |
| ... | ... |
| 202209 | 20000000 |

Table A is approximately 20 million rows and 10 columns

I want to join it with table B, a large table of hundreds of millions of rows and hundreds of columns, partitioned by column `PK_MONTH` in partitions of approximately 20 millions rows each:

| PK_MONTH | PK_ID | COL_A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202209 | 3 | 'abc' |
| .... | ... | ... |
| 202009 | 19999999 | 'def' |
| .... | ... | ... |
| 202001 | 5 | 'xyz' |
| .... | ... | ... |
| 202001 | 19999789 | 'qwe' |

I want to join column `ID` from tabla A with data from table B of a specific partition, let's say from partition `PK_MONTH = 202209`. Since I'm only interested in data from that partition, I can join them in the following ways:

```
SELECT
    T0.ID
    , T1.*
FROM TABLE_A T0
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B T1
    ON T0.ID = T1.PK_ID
    AND T0.MONTH = T1.PK_MONTH /* <--- join on column */

;
```

Or

```
SELECT
    T0.ID
    , T1.*
FROM TABLE_A T0
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B T1
    ON T0.ID = T1.PK_ID
    AND T1.PK_MONTH = 202209 /* <--- join on value */
;
```

My question is: **are the two queries equally efficient/fast? If (not) so, why?**

I'm using Oracle SQL.

I thank you in advance.

Comment: Different queries, probably different results. What have you experienced when running them? Have you compared the explain plans? https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: You need to check execution plans of both your queries and probably test a runtime on real data

Comment: I get your point, but I don't know how to read the execution plan, will check it.